# com.here.android.mpa.search.PlaceRequest cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable

Tags: java, android, here-api

The HEAR API classes for Android do not appear to be serializable so that when using fragments, you cannot pass them as arguments to the fragments.
Is there a way around that?

I have a Recycler list showing PlaceLink titles and other data.  When I click on an item in the list I need to send the PlaceLink to the new fragment.  I call the getInstance method and pass the PlaceLink and then try to add the PlaceLink to the arguments bundle.  However, you can't because it isn't Serializable and so you can't add it via putSerializable.

Here is the code in my Fragment that I need to use:

```
public static RestaurantFoundDetails newInstance(PlaceLink placeLink) {
    RestaurantFoundDetails fragment = new RestaurantFoundDetails();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM1, placeLink);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

There seems to be no workaround to this if I use the HEAR API!

If you try to work around it, you get this error when your app is paused:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.here.android.mpa.search.PlaceLink@4312236b
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1772)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:926)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1719)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:838)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1542)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1232)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:878)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:123)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1462)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:619)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1791)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1697)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:838)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1542)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1232)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4604)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3934)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not available in HereSDK and currently there are no plans to implement it.

BR